# Control number of buckets created in an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In **Elasticsearch** there's a limit on how many buckets you can create in an aggregation. If it creates more buckets than the specified limit, you will get a warning message In **ES 6.x** and an error will be thrown in future versions.

Here's the warning message:

> This aggregation creates too many buckets (10001) and will throw an error in future versions. You should update the [search.max_buckets] cluster setting or use the [composite] aggregation to paginate all buckets in multiple requests.

Since **ES 7.x**, that limit is set to `10000` which can be adjusted, though.

The problem is, I can't actually calculate (or estimate) how many buckets an aggregation is going to create.

Consider the following request:

```
GET /zone_stats_hourly/_search
{
   "aggs":{
      "apps":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"appId",
            "size":<NUM_TERM_BUCKETS>,
            "min_doc_count":1,
            "shard_min_doc_count":0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error":false,
            "order":[
               {
                  "_count":"desc"
               },
               {
                  "_key":"asc"
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggregations":{
            "histogram":{
               "days":{
                  "field":"processTime",
                  "time_zone":"UTC",
                  "interval":"1d",
                  "offset":0,
                  "order":{
                     "_key":"asc"
                  },
                  "keyed":false,
                  "min_doc_count":0
               },
               "aggregations":{
                  "requests":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"requests"
                     }
                  },
                  "filled":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"filledRequests"
                     }
                  },
                  "matched":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"matchedRequests"
                     }
                  },
                  "imp":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"impressions"
                     }
                  },
                  "cv":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"completeViews"
                     }
                  },
                  "clicks":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"clicks"
                     }
                  },
                  "installs":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"installs"
                     }
                  },
                  "actions":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"actions"
                     }
                  },
                  "earningsIRT":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"earnings.inIRT"
                     }
                  },
                  "earningsUSD":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"earnings.inUSD"
                     }
                  },
                  "earningsEUR":{
                     "sum":{
                        "field":"earnings.inEUR"
                     }
                  },
                  "dealBasedEarnings":{
                     "nested":{
                        "path":"dealBasedEarnings"
                     },
                     "aggregations":{
                        "types":{
                           "terms":{
                              "field":"dealBasedEarnings.type",
                              "size":4,
                              "min_doc_count":1,
                              "shard_min_doc_count":0,
                              "show_term_doc_count_error":false,
                              "order":[
                                 {
                                    "_count":"desc"
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "_key":"asc"
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           "aggregations":{
                              "dealBasedEarningsIRT":{
                                 "sum":{
                                    "field":"dealBasedEarnings.amount.inIRT"
                                 }
                              },
                              "dealBasedEarningsUSD":{
                                 "sum":{
                                    "field":"dealBasedEarnings.amount.inUSD"
                                 }
                              },
                              "dealBasedEarningsEUR":{
                                 "sum":{
                                    "field":"dealBasedEarnings.amount.inEUR"
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size":0,
   "_source":{
      "excludes":[]
   },
   "stored_fields":["*"],
   "docvalue_fields":[
      {
         "field":"eventTime",
         "format":"date_time"
      },
      {
         "field":"processTime",
         "format":"date_time"
      },
      {
         "field":"postBack.time",
         "format":"date_time"
      }
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "range":{
                  "processTime":{
                     "from":1565049600000,
                     "to":1565136000000,
                     "include_lower":true,
                     "include_upper":false,
                     "boost":1.0
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "adjust_pure_negative":true,
         "boost":1.0
      }
   }
}
```

If I set `<NUM_TERM_BUCKETS>` to `2200` and perform the request, I get the warning message that says I'm creating more than `10000` buckets (how?!).

A sample response from **ES**:

```
#! Deprecation: 299 Elasticsearch-6.7.1-2f32220 "This aggregation creates too many buckets (10001) and will throw an error in future versions. You should update the [search.max_buckets] cluster setting or use the [composite] aggregation to paginate all buckets in multiple requests."
{
  "took": 6533,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 103456,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "apps": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 9,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 37395,
      "buckets":[...]
    }
  }
}
```

More interestingly, after decreasing `<NUM_TERM_BUCKETS>` to `2100`, I get no warning messages, which means the number of buckets created is below `10000`.

I've had a hard time to find the reason behind that and found NOTHING.

Is there any formula or something to calculate or estimate the number of buckets that an aggregation is going to create before actually performing the request?

I want to know if an aggregation throws error in **ES 7.x** or later regarding to a specified `search.max_buckets`, so that I can decide whether to use the `composite` aggregation or not.

**UPDATE**

I tried a much simpler aggregation containing no nested or sub aggregations on an index having roughly `80000` documents.

Here is the request:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "unique":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"_id",
            "size":<NUM_TERM_BUCKETS>
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If I set the `<NUM_TERM_BUCKETS>` to `7000`, I get this error response in **ES 7.3**:

```
{
   "error":{
      "root_cause":[
         {
            "type":"too_many_buckets_exception",
            "reason":"Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting.",
            "max_buckets":10000
         }
      ],
      "type":"search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason":"all shards failed",
      "phase":"query",
      "grouped":true,
      "failed_shards":[
         {
            "shard":0,
            "index":"my_index",
            "node":"XYZ",
            "reason":{
               "type":"too_many_buckets_exception",
               "reason":"Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting.",
               "max_buckets":10000
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status":503
}
```

And it runs successfully if I decrease the `<NUM_TERM_BUCKETS>` to `6000`.

Seriously, I'm confused. how on earth this aggregation creates more than `10000` buckets? Can anyone answer this?

Comment: Using the `cardinality` aggregation you can actually have a good idea of how many buckets your `terms` aggregation is going to create.

Comment: Sounds good, but not ideal. this requires an extra request to be performed on ES :/

Comment: Ok, but how do you expect to set `NUM_TERM_BUCKETS` without doing so?

Comment: Why setting `NUM_TERM_BUCKETS` to `2200` causes the aggregation to create more than `10000` buckets, but setting it to `2100` doesn't? how to find the optimal value of `NUM_TERM_BUCKETS` (which is between `2100` and `2200`) using the response of the `cardinality` aggregation?

Comment: You have nested buckets as well, the 10000 count is for all leaf buckets (terms + nested terms). You'd be better off using the `composite` aggregation and paginate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_shard_size_3):

> The `shard_size` parameter can be used to minimize the extra work that
>   comes with bigger requested `size`. When defined, it will determine how
>   many terms the coordinating node will request from each shard. Once
>   all the shards responded, the coordinating node will then reduce them
>   to a final result which will be based on the `size` parameter - this
>   way, one can increase the accuracy of the returned terms and avoid the
>   overhead of streaming a big list of buckets back to the client.
>
> The default `shard_size` is `(size * 1.5 + 10)`.

To address issues of accuracy in a distributed system, **Elasticsearch** asks for a number higher than `size` from each shard.

So, the maximum value of `NUM_TERM_BUCKETS` for a simple terms aggregation can be calculated using the following formula:

```
maxNumTermBuckets = (search.maxBuckets - 10) / 1.5
```

which is `6660` for `search.maxBuckets = 10000`.